# Determine if polygon has a hole?

Tags: math, graphics, polygon, triangulation

After experimenting with some triangulation work I ran across the question on how to determine if a polygon has a hole?

I know how to handle a known hole but am unsure of how to determine if one exists.

**Example:**

Given the following vertices:

```
0 ( 0, 0)
1 ( 0,20)
2 (20,20)
3 ( 0,20)
4 ( 2, 2)
5 ( 6, 2)
6 ( 6, 6)
7 ( 2, 6)
```

How do I know if it is a simple polygon such as:

[image]

or a non-simple/complex polygon like:

[image]

I ask because the data that I will have to work with has the potential of being a polygon with a hole, but I will have no knowledge beforehand of it being so.

**note:** the polygon will *never* be complex. I just need to know when the vertices of the outside of the polygon ends and the vertices comprising the hole begin.

Comment: if you just need to detect when the polygon has closed isn't just a matter of checking if the point has appeared already?

Comment: A polygon is closed when the segments do connect at the beginning and end. That is, you start to draw the line at a point and finish at the same point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the vertices alone you cannot infer the layout of the polygon's edges. You will need to keep the edges as well (for example as pairs of vertices).

In your example, another graph layout would be, for instance, 0-1-5-6-2-3-7-4-0 where the resulting polygon contains no hole at all.

If you have the edges, you can align them so that they form circles, i.e. group those with common second/first element together: (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0) and (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 4). If there is a hole, there will be two or more such groups which cannot be grouped together any further. You can then find out whose points are within the area surrounded by the other points to know where the hole is.

Answer (score 3):

I have yet too low reputation to comment on an answer, but I want to say that I strongly recommend to follow mathematical convention regarding holes. The outer polygon should go anti clockwise and the hole should always go clockwise. MATLAB does this in reverse order, but that goes then for both polygon (clockwise) and holes (anti-clockwise)

Comment: Huh, I was not aware of that. I will keep that in mind for the future! Do you happen to have any further reading on this particular matter?

Comment: This is fundamental mathemathics and many theorems are based on this fact. A few very simple ways to find out if a curve is a hole or a outer boundary uses the fact that holes have another orientation. Search for "Curve orientation" (¤) on wikipedia. To find out if a polygon is a hole or another adjacent polygon you can for example sum the areas that each pair of adjacent nodes span up. If the sum is positive there is a outer boundary and a negative sum means that it is a hole. You can also vectorize the vertices and sum their cross products as described in (¤).

Answer (score 2):

Figure out [if two non-adjacent line segments intersect](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/95/line_segs), and you will find the split between the hole and the polygon. Yes, this algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>), but a bit of foreknowledge can help cut down the number of tests.

Comment: This would help only if he had a set of the polygon's segments.

Comment: This does assume that adjacent vertices form edges, which is not that big a stretch.

Comment: What exactly are adjacent vertices? As far as I know, the adjacency of vertices is established through edges ... If your definition of adjacency is "points which are close together", then the green-coloured polygon would never be formed (because 4 is closer to 0 than any other point, so there would be an edge (0, 4).)

Comment: @Felix: If you look at the question you'll notice that the asker has numbered the vertices 0 through 7. Adjacent vertices would be ones whose index differs by 1, or the last and first vertices in the sequence.

Comment: In that case, there would be an edge (3, 4) which does not exist in the example ...

Comment: Of course it doesn't exist. Using my algorithm would determine that it crosses with (0, 7), **which means that those pairs separate the outside from the hole, just as I said**.

Answer (score 0):

you can select a point from one circle "B" and judge whether the selected point is inside or outside another circle "A". If is, then you get the hole. If not, then you select a point from the circle A and judge whether the point is inside the circle B, if is, you get the holes.